# CASE WHEN - Multiple Conditions - Over Multiple Rows of same reference

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case, rows, multiple-conditions

I am trying to create a flag by using CASE WHEN to determine something but it keeps returning "single_state" - I guess because its not applying the CASE WHEN to all rows with o/n 1234 which is the bit I need help with.

My expected output is to have "multi_state" for the first 3 lines as they are all the same o/n and "single_state" for the last line as its neither grouped or got more than 1 state.

Example below:

DATA Table

```
o/n      sku     order_type    state   state_check
1234    ABC987    Grouped     express
1234    BCD654    Grouped     arrived
1234    CDF321    Grouped     shipped
5679    GBT104   Not Grouped  express
```

Query

```
SELECT o/n, SKU, order_type, state, 
CASE WHEN order_type is "Grouped" AND (state = "express" AND state = "arrived") THEN "multi_state"
CASE WHEN order_type is "Grouped" AND (state = "express" AND state = "shipped") THEN "multi_state"
ELSE "single_state"
END AS state_check
FROM data.table
```

Comment: Please *tag* your specific RDBMS

Comment: Your order numbers 1234 all have *Grouped* for `order_type` so does this not already provide the information you need? `case when order_type='grouped' then 'multistate' else 'singlestate' end`...?

Comment: Please tag your request with the DBMS you are using. My answer for instance is standard SQL, but your DBMS may still not be compliant with the query. Always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS in order to only get answers that work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a window function (an aggregation function with an `OVER` clause) to look at multiple rows at once.

```
SELECT 
  "o/n", sku, order_type, state,
  CASE
    WHEN order_type <> 'Grouped' THEN
      'single_state'
    WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT state) OVER (PARTITION BY "o/n", order_type) = 1 THEN
      'single_state'
    ELSE
      'multi_state'
  END
FROM data.table
ORDER BY "o/n", sku;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `CASE`s for `multi_state` both check that `state` has the values `express` and `arrived`/`shipped` at the same time. A single column cannot have multiple values at the same time.

You can use `IN()` to accept multiple values as `multi_state`:

```sql
SELECT o/n
    , sku
    , order_type
    , state
    , CASE
        WHEN order_type = 'Grouped' AND state IN('express', 'arrived', 'shipped') THEN 'multi_state'
        ELSE 'single_state'
    END AS state_check
FROM data.table
```